# How to prevent Gmail from creating map link from address?

Tags: html, node.js, google-maps

I am sending an email to my colleague through node mailer, I am attaching the address at the footer and gmail enables the link to map of the same. How to remove that?

Comment: I guess that's the GMail client that do it. I think you cannot prevent that, as this is Google parsing the incomming mail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this:

```
<a href=javascript:void(0)>
Some Address Line 1<br>Some Address Line 2<br>Pincode<br>Country
</a>
```

and you can disable that feature.